# How do I get rid of browser redirect malware?

Tags: leopard, dns

I am using Mac OS X Leopard on a MacBook Pro.

I must have been very careless at some point, since I managed to let some malware install in it.

While browsing I get randomly redirected to different web sites than those I intended to visit, both from Safari and from Google Chrome.

I have tried to clean my computer with ClamXav without any success so far.

Comment: If you upgrade to snow leopard, you get the Apple anti-malware built in to the OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your DNS might be hijacked, which could be your router or your Mac.

I'd suggest using OpenDNS for a while to see if the behaviour stops.  If it does, then you will need to look at getting your DNS reconfigured.

If the behaviour continues then it may be malware but honestly I can't think of a single one that would do this.

Comment: Thanks. I think you might be right. I am going to try OpenDNS. I am also going to check your suggestion about Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check your proxy settings too (click on Advanced after you select the interface you're using, then the tab labeled Proxies). You should only see *.local, 169.254/16 in the bottom box, and none of the boxes should be checked (unless you use a proxy, in which case you probably know what is what).

Comment: I checked but none of the boxes were checked and the "Bypass proxy settings" text is set to `*.local, 169.254/16`. Thanks for the info.